# Setting Specific UITableView rows to push in a specific detail view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I currently have 7 rows in my UITableView and I'm using segues to push in a detail view. However, I currently have two different view controllers, and want something like this:

*If row 1 and 2 are selected push in: "showMenuDetail1"
If row 3 through 4 are selected push in: showMenuDetail2"*

This is what I currently have: I'm not sure how to exactly assign rows to a specific one.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showMenuDetail1"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.menuTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        HomeDetailViewController *HDViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        HDViewController.theName = [[menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! I know it's an if and else statement but I'm not sure how to write out the exact condition. Thanks!

Comment: you want to goo to showMenuDetail1 view from current view if row 1 and 2  is selected and showMenuDetail2 view if row 3 and 4 is selected

Comment: Yupp that's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Create two segues.  The important idea is to *not* attach either to the table view cells, instead drag them both from the view controller containing the table to their respective destinations.  Give them each an identifier.

Then in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, examine the `indexPath.row` and trigger the appropriate segue.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row < 2) { // or whatever
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueForRows0and1" sender:self];
    }
    // etc...
}
```

You can still implement prepareForSegue if you need it, including, if you need it, referring to the tableView's `indexPathForSelectedRow`.

Comment: Thank you danh, however I'm getting an error with 'self'. **no visible @interface for uitableview declares the selector 'performseguewithidentifier** I made sure to hook up the segues with the viewController, and nothing. I currently have a UITableView inside a view controller.

Comment: try to import `detailView.h` and then  `[detailview performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSuccessful" sender:self]`

Comment: @user1886754, sorry, it's - (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender.  See the UIViewController docs.  Edited answer to reflect this.

Comment: @user1886754, that error is telling you that you're sending it to the table view rather than the controller (and the capitalization is all wrong if that's what you actually had).